# Is this answer acceptable for the derivative of $\tan(\arcsin t)$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I got $\frac{\sec^2(\arcsin t)}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}$, however my textbook shows $\frac{1}{(1-t^2)^{3/2}}$.  Would my answer be acceptable on a test?

If not, how do I get to the correct answer?

Thanks

Comment: Well $csc^2(x)=\frac{1}{1-\sin^2x}$

Comment: I think you ought to simplify first. Note that $\tan=\frac{\sin}{\cos}$ and $\cos(\arcsin t)=\sqrt{1-t^2}$.

Comment: Every teacher has his own ways.  I would take points off if you didn't simplify that.  I let some simplifications go, but this one matters.  I consider it part of the required material that calculus student can simplify trig(arctrig) things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is correct, but notice that:
$$
\sec^2(\arcsin t) = \frac{1}{\cos^2(\arcsin t)} = \frac{1}{1-\sin^2(\arcsin t)}  = \frac{1}{1-t^2}
$$

Answer (score 3):

Remember the following identities:

$$\sec^2(z)=\frac 1{\cos^2 z}$$

$$\cos \arcsin z = {\sqrt {1-z^2}}$$

substitution in your case gave the desired equality.